CMake Could NOT find Iconv
I don't know if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything useful through Google.
I am trying to compile xoreos-tools to better understand how it works. I am just adding std::cout to debug it.
I am using Windows 10 and I know Windows isn't particularly friendly to open source. I download the repository and tried to use CMake 3.29.3 x64 to configure it, it doesn't work:
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:20 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Iconv (missing: Iconv_LIBRARY Iconv_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindIconv.cmake:165 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:266 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

Iconv isn't found. I googled it and found this, and I downloaded it then installed it.
I then added the paths to the system environment variables:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"Iconv_LIBRARY"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\lib\\libiconv.lib"
"Iconv_INCLUDE_DIR"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\include"


And I then closed CMake and reopened it, same error. Checking the environment used by CMake I haven't found the variables I just added. So I added these variables using CMake's environment editor, then tried again. Same error.
I tried to add entries to the big box in the main window using "Add Entry" button, same error.
Everything I have tried have failed, and I am out of ideas. How can I fix this?

Variables listed in the "missing" list are CMake variables, not environment ones. If you want to hint about the package location, you could set e.g. CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable. This variable could be environment one: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html

*Edit: Iconv is really named libiconv
I came here from a missing pkgconfig and other dependencies.
pkgconfig was fixed with:

choco install pkgconfiglite

Then ran the vcpkg installs as suggested by Ξένη Γήινος
I've just discovered it today and it worked like a charm.
ps. Not sure that I needed Boost, and it installs a lot of stuff.
